# What kind of noun is "language"?

Tags: nouns, parts-of-speech

Exactly what kind of a noun is "language" in this metaphorical sentence?

> Music is beautiful **language**.

Comment: My gut expects "a beautiful language"...

Comment: Mine too, but either way works.  Different connotation though. Either Music IS literally a language (which it arguably is, with both written and audio forms, a syntax, and punctuation); or instances of music are just metaphorically "language", because they "speak to us" somehow.

Comment: Language is beautiful music. What type of noun is music? @Stephie, do you expect "a beautiful music" there?

Comment: @TRomano But we say *Water is a substance* not *Water is substance*. And *(A) substance is (a) water* doesn't really work, IMHO.

Comment: @Damkerng T.  Are you suggesting that *substance*, *art*, *music*, and *language* are all the same kind of noun?

Comment: @TRomano My idea was that not all nouns work the same way, and the copula *be* sometimes is directional. For me, the meaning should come first, and meaning can help resolve the syntactic category, but syntax can force how we should interpret the meaning. *Music is a beautiful language* could mean one thing, while *Music is beautiful language*, given that it's a valid sentence, should mean a different thing.

Comment: @Damkerng T.  Agreed. If we have an abstraction that refers to a paradigm or essence (Art, Music, Language -- by convention we use upper case) we don't use the article. Consider a treatise on metaphysics in which the author makes a distinction between Substance and Idea.  In such a treatise one would accept as grammatical the question "Is a drop of water on the back of your hand Substance or Idea?"  and the answer "Water is Substance".  Now consider a textbook on crime-scene forensics: "The investigator should test the substance to determine whether it is organic or inorganic."

Comment: @NANDAGOPAL How is "language" an uncountable noun? It has a plural - "languages".

Comment: Yeah, that was stupid of me.. sorry.

Answer (score 4):

"Language" is a **common abstract noun**. An abstract noun is, to put it simply, a **thing which cannot be touched**; a noun which expresses an idea, quality or state rather than a physical object. *(Paraphrased from Google)*

The other type of common noun is the concrete noun. This is the noun which is most common; for example, "dog", "computer", "table". Common nouns do not require a capital letter except in obvious circumstances such as the beginning of a sentence.